# Buy and send postcard from Toluca, Mexico?

Tags: mexico, mail, mexico-city

I've seen topic asking about sending postcards from MEX airport, but I'm currently based in Toluca (on a company project) with very little spare time but I would like to send some postcards to Europe. What is the best course of action? I didn't see or found any post office nearby and the travel agency in my hotel does not sell postcards.

We may have one day off, but we are planning trip to Teotihuacan. Will it be easier there? Like more tourist-oriented infrastructure?

Comment: It is very hard for me to imagine that you need a touristic location in order to send postcards. Why not ask at the reception of your hotel? They probably know the place better than anyone else.

Comment: You bet I asked, they aren't very cooperative and think that I will have to get to centre of town(what, as stated, I don't have time for unfortunately). If they own travel agency doesn't have them I think it's bad sign

Comment: If you go to Teotihuacan, I think you will find that shops selling postcards will be glad to sell stamps, too.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus hi, we were on a trip to Teotihuacan last weekend and as long as it's easy to get postcards everywhere no one has stamps. Literally, not a single shop is selling them, as they can't make profit out of it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I didn't see this at the time, but for anyone interested in sending post cards from Mexico, I will record my experience with this.  I will qualify it by saying that my experiences with the Mexican postal service are not recent, and it's possible that by some miracle, postal service in Mexico has completely changed since I lived there.

My experience was that the best way to ensure that a letter or postcard did not get lost was to take it to the Post Office in person and give it to a clerk at a window (rather than putting it through a slot in a mailbox).

However, given a choice between mailing a letter or postcard from Mexico on day N, and taking it with me and mailing it from a first world country on day N + 3, the latter would get the letter to its destination quicker.